# Can't regex over created list

Tags: python

I want to:

1. Pull number from parentheses "javascript:analysis(XXXXXXX)" for each game
2. Create a list with direct hyperlinks like: http://www.nowgoal.cc/analysis/XXXXXXX.html
3. Many many more...

Code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import re

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('READY!')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    page = Page('http://www.nowgoal.cc/')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    lista = []

    for x in soup.find_all("a", attrs={'title' : 'Match analyze'}):
        lista.append(x)

    for element in lista:
        z = re.search(r"\((.......\))",element)
        if z:
            print(z.groups())

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Python yields: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I struggle with this for a few days now, don't have more ideas to fix this. I digged and tried, searched and ended clueless. I really want to write more code and develop my idea. Please help, I'm dying here.

Comment: Please post the full exception. At what line does this exception occur, and what is the traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zzb.py", line 47, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "zzb.py", line 43, in main
    z = re.search(r"\((.......\))",element)
  File "C:\Users\Hans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

The elements that are returned by `soup.find_all` are not strings. They are objects. Except each object has their respective `__str__` methods overridden for human readability.

So you are not passing strings into search. But in fact customized beautiful soup objects.

```
for element in lista:
    z = re.search(r"\((.......\))",element)
    if z:
        print(z.groups())
```

To fix, make sure to convert `element` into a string before calling the respective method.

```
for element in lista:
    z = re.search(r"\((.......\))", str(element))
    if z:
        print(z.groups())
```

Comment: Great! Back to basics again. Feeling dumb that it was so simple. Thank You Alan!